# Proof involving maximum weight of edge in minimum spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, trees

Let $G$ be a minimum spanning tree of a complete graph. Let $e$ be the maximum weight edge in $G$. I'd like to proof that given any other spanning tree $G'$ of this graph, being $j$ the maximum weight edge of $G'$, then $w(e) \leq w(j)$.

I really don't know if this is true, and I can't think of any counterexample to proof the opposite.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, that doesn't seem right.  Set all edge weights to 1.  Then $w(e) = 1 = w(j)$, so we can't have $w(e) < w(j)$.  What I think should be true is $w(e) \leq w(j)$.

Comment: Yes, makes sense, I'll edit

Comment: Hint: Think of the cut property of the minimum spanning tree problem. In any cut which includes $e$, we know that $e$ must be the minimum weight edge in this cut. Any spanning tree $G'$ must contain at least one edge from this cut. Hence $w(e) \le w(j)$. And we are done.

Answer (score 4):

The cut property of the Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) problem is what you should look at. i.e. Any edge $\{x,y\}$ in an MST has weight at least as small as the edge with smallest weight in the cut that separates $x$ and $y$. This can easily be shown by contradiction.

In any cut which includes the edge $e$ (i.e. separates it's two adjacent vertices), we know that $e$ must be an edge with minimum weight in this cut.

Any spanning tree $G'$ must contain at least one edge in this cut.

Let $e'$ be such an edge. We know that 
$$w(e') \ge w(e)$$
We also know that 
$$w(j) \ge w(e')$$
So,
$$w(j) \ge w(e') \ge w(e)$$

Comment: How can you assume that $w(j) \geq w(e')$ ?  For instance you could have $e', j$ and $e$ all in the same cut, and I don't see what prevents $w(e') > w(j)$.  In fact, the point is that if $w(j) < w(e)$ then $G'$ uses no edge in the cut of $e$, and thus $G'$ can't be a spanning tree.

Comment: The cut property as described on wikipedia is quite different from what I'm referring to (maybe I should delete the link then and state it explicitly).

Comment: But still, say that $e'$ is the (single) edge with the highest weight in the graph, and $G'$ doesn't include it.  Then $w(j) < w(e')$.

Comment: I don't see what you are saying. Isn't $w(j)$ the largest weight in $G'$? Note that $j \in G'$ and $e' \in G'$.

Comment: Ah everything is fine then.  My apologies !  I though $e'$ was any edge in the cut, not one included by $G'$.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the cut property definition?